# sendOSCMsg is not defined on Kivy (Windows Shell)

Tags: windows, kivy, osc

I tried another attempt with this

## kivy 1.9.0

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from simpleOSC import initOSCClient, initOSCServer, closeOSC, \
        setOSCHandler, sendOSCMsg





class OscShowcase(BoxLayout):

    pass

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(OscShowcase, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #self.but_Osc = Button(text='Press to show Osc')
        #self.but_Osc.bind(on_release=self.send_Osc)
        #self.add_widget(self.but_Osc)


    def send_Osc(self, *l):
        pass
        #sendOSCMsg('/chaine_en_dur/', [2.0])

    def sendOSCMsg( address='/print', data=[] ) :
        m = OSCMessage()
        m.setAddress(address)
        for d in data :
            m.append(d)
        basic_client.send(m)

class OscWidget(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(OscWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class TestOscApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return OscShowcase()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    host = '127.0.0.1'
    sport = 9000
    rport = 9001

    # osc

    initOSCClient(host, sport)
    initOSCServer(host, rport)
    TestOscApp().run()
```

## .kv file

```
<OscShowcase>:

    BoxLayout:

        OscWidget:

            Button:

                text: 'OSC'
                pos: (700, 500)
                # on_release : sendOSCMsg('')

                # sendOSCMsg: '/chaine_en_dur/', [2.0]
                # on_release : self.but_Osc.bind()
                group: 'OscButton'
                on_press: sendOSCMsg('2')
```

I still get an error "NameError: name 'sendOSCMsg is not defined" when I press the button. Is anybody can help me to understand why? I would like to send osc messages out to Max MSP

Answer (score 0):

Kv Lang has some scopes, you can [read more about it here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#rule-context)

> There are three keywords specific to Kv language:
>
> - app: always refers to the instance of your application.
> - root: refers to the base widget/template in the current rule
> - self: always refer to the current widget

You can run a method from **TestOscApp** with `app.method_name()` and from **OscShowcase** with `root.method_name()`

So, just update your kv to call **sendOSCMsg** from **OscShowcase**:

```
on_press: root.sendOSCMsg('2')
```